# probleam 0xc0000142 how to solve

Tags: windows-7

I use Windows 7 and I install pes 2016 now.

I have a system error

> "The application was unable to start correctly"

[image]

Comment: How did you acquire PES 2016? Through steam?

Answer (score 1):

This is a component of DirectX. You may need to update your DirectX runtimes.

You can find the download for this from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35&wt.mc_id=mscom_en_us_search_mssuggests_131z4enus22051), or [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=34429) if the web installer has any issue.